# magento update attribute1 = attribute2

Tags: magento

I have 800 products in my magento store and im trying to change all SKUs, but keep the old ones to another text field. I have found a script that changes all SKUs at once but the problem is that first, i have to insert the text of attribute field SKU, to a new attribute field "old_sku".

How can i update old_sku = sku?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just label right ? What purpose you doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it really simple then the solution is

a) Add an attribute "old_sku"
b) Export all products
b) Change the CSV - Copy & paste the "sku" column values in "old_sku" and,
d) Import all products

that's it

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: exporting all products, deleting all products, modifying CSV, importing.. and for what, just cloning one attribute values..

Comment: No need to delete the products as if sku is used then it will update on the same sku, the above solution is for saving the sku to other attribute and not changing the sku values present.

Comment: Thanks all for the help, i did export all products as @GreatIndianBrain said, delete all columns except sku and old_sku, copy all data from one column to the other and created a profile for import. I checked all products and old_sku is updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you do have some PHP knowledge, you could use it to create a PHP script that runs once and replaces all the attribute values. For example, i would do that like so:

```
<?php
// Magento initialization code; taken from here: http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/06/01/application-bootstrap-in-magento.html
require 'app/Mage.php';

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

$initializationCode = 'admin';
$initializationType = 'store';
$scope = 'frontend';
Mage::app($initializationCode, $initializationType);
Mage::getConfig()->init();
Mage::getConfig()->loadEventObservers($scope);
Mage::app()->addEventArea($scope);

// Update products
try
{
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product->setOldSku($product->getSku())->save();
    }
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Something bad happened: {$e->getMessage()}. Shutting down...";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Just create, let's say, a `update_skus.php` file within the root directory of your Magento setup (near the `index.php` file), fill it with the code i've provided and navigate your browser to that file (e. g. `http://magento.local/update_skus.php`). You should get all the products having their `old_sku` attribute set exactly to their `sku` attribute' values.

Comment: I will try it now. Just a question regardind the code. Yesterday, I  updated the sku and oldsku of 30 products from the admin, one by one. Is it possible to update oldsku only if no value in the field, so i will not lose the data of the 30 products; Thanks

Comment: sure! just alter the PHP code adding the line `if (empty($product->getOldSku()))` before `$product->setOldSku($product->getSku())->save();`

Comment: I run the php file and i get a white screen. Also i checked a few products at the admin and the oldsku is not updated, just empty.

Comment: Where do i get the values for the "$initializationCode = 'admin'; and
$initializationType = 'store';" ? I think i have to change them

Comment: First of all, let's talk about the products. Saying _the old_sku attribute_ i mean you got the attribute with the code __old_sku__. If values for it are not set - take a look at logs at `var/log/exception.log` and `var/log/system.log` and Apache logs.

Comment: Now, `$initializationCode` and `$initializationType` are the fixed-value variables. Think of them as of constants. Magento should take care of those to initialize correctly. You could take a look at the link i've provided in the source code.